# "/dev/bin/load.sh[425]: : cannot open" - Linux file redirect to empty string

Tags: linux, file, redirect, pipe

The below command is throwing error for some users. Can any one please explain why the error is occurring only for some users. The $EMPTY_STRING is empty for all the users.

echo $OUTPUT > $EMPTY_STRING

Answer (score 0):

When I run this in my bash terminal:

```
$ echo aaa > ''
bash: : No such file or directory
```

so I guess */dev/bin/load.sh[425]* just refers to the script you are running. I doubt `$EMPTY_STRING` is empty because in that case error would be different (if you are in bash):

```
$ a=''
$ echo aaa> $a
bash: $a: ambiguous redirect
```

You can try to compare their `env` and make sure these users are using same shell.

Answer (score 0):

Jhutar,

You are correct, /dev/bin/load.sh is the script that has the line of code I mentioned. The actual code in the script is "echo $OUTPUT > $TMPFILE".

However, the variable $TMPFILE is not defined anywhere in the OS. I printed the value in the log file just before the above mentioned code line and it's empty.

There must be some Linux setting enabled for some users and the compiler is not throwing any error when STDOUT is redirected to an undefined varaible.

I know the below code will not throw any error.

echo $OUTPUT > /dev/null

Is there any Linux setting that can treat all the undefined varaibles as "/dev/null"?